# VB BC30516 error code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hello I got a problem with my VB and I'm pretty new and just got this error code and I don't know what to do

Error

> BC30516    Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Text' accepts this number of arguments.

here is my code

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If TextBox1.Text = 1 Then
        TextBox2.Text("Tag ikke afsted")

    End If

    If TextBox1.Text = 2 Then
        TextBox2.Text("Tag ikke afsted")

    End If

    If TextBox1.Text = 3 Then
        TextBox2.Text("Tag ikke afsted")

    End If

    If TextBox1.Text = 4 Then
        TextBox2.Text("CTF 2 hold-TeamDeatchmatch Rush")

    End If

    If TextBox1.Text = 5 Then
        TextBox2.Text("CTF 2 hold-TeamDeath")

    End If

    If TextBox1.Text = 6 Then
        TextBox2.Text("CTF 3 hold-TeamDeathmatch 2 hold-TeamDeathmatch")

    End If

    If TextBox1.Text = 7 Then
        TextBox2.Text("CTF 2 hold-TeamDeathmatch")

    End If

    If TextBox1.Text = 8 Then
        TextBox2.Text("CTF 2 hold-TeamDeathmatch")

    End If

    If TextBox1.Text = 9 Then
        TextBox2.Text("CTF 3 hold-teamDeathmatch 2 hold-TeamDeathmatch")

    End If

    If TextBox1.Text = 10 Then
        TextBox2.Text("CTF 2 hold-TeamDeathmatch")

    End If

    If TextBox1.Text = 11 Then
        TextBox2.Text = ("CTF 3 hold-TeamDeathmatch 2 holdTeamDeathmatch")

    End If

    If TextBox1.Text = 12 Then
        TextBox2.Text = ("CTF 3 hold-TeamDeathmatch 2 hold-TeamDeathmatch")

    End If

    If TextBox1.Text = 13 Then
        TextBox2.Text = ("CTF 3 hold-TeamDeathmatch 2 hold-TeamDeathmatch")

    End If

    If TextBox1.Text = 14 Then
        TextBox2.Text = ("CTF 3 hold-TeamDeathmatch 2 hold-TeamDeathmatch")

    End If

    If TextBox1.Text = 15 Then
        TextBox2.Text = ("CTF 3 hold-TeamDeathmatch 2 hold-TeamDeathmatch")

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If TextBox2.Text = ("CTF") Then
        Timer1.Start()
    End If

    If TextBox1.Text = ("3 hold-TeamDeathmatch") Then
        Timer2.Start()
    End If

    If TextBox1.Text = ("2 hold-TeamDeathmatch") Then
        Timer3.Start()
    End If

    If TextBox1.Text = ("Rush") Then
        Timer4.Start()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar1.Increment(50)
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        Shell("C:\Users\lasse\hardball\2tdm.bat")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    ProgressBar2.Increment(50)
    If ProgressBar2.Value = 100 Then
        Timer2.Stop()
        Shell("C:\Users\lasse\hardball\3tdm.bat")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
    ProgressBar3.Increment(50)
    If ProgressBar3.Value = 100 Then
        Timer3.Stop()
        Shell("C:\Users\lasse\hardball\ctf.bat")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer4_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer4.Tick
    ProgressBar4.Increment(50)
    If ProgressBar4.Value = 100 Then
        Timer4.Stop()
        Shell("C:\Users\lasse\hardball\rush.bat")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Whats wrong with the code?

Here is a screenshot of it.

https://gyazo.com/b01cd6aea0eaf804ba9530e4ccc3fda1

Comment: `TextBox2.Text("Tag ikke afsted")` - Text is a property, not a method.

Comment: Don't spam tags. Doing so is not helpful and will most likely attract downvotes.

Comment: `TextBox2.Text = "Tag ikke afsted"` is the correct way to set the Text property of a Textbox control.